# display list with the JS DOM

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom

I have an array with 8 objects. I am using a loop to get the values of each items. And I want to display them in a div in my html file. I'd like to display only 4 of them (for the moment! but after I want to replace those images automatically  when I delete them).

I know I could use a splice() method or a slice() method. But I'd like to know if it is possible to do it whitout creating a new array ? Because I want my for loop transforming all the objects into images in one time.

```js
const data = [
   {
   image_name: "Image1",
   image_id: "0",
   source: "images/img1.png",},
  {
   image_name: "Image2",
   image_id: "1",
   source: "images/img2.png",
  },
  {
    image_name: "Image3",
    image_id: "2",
    source: "images/img3.png",
  },
  {
    image_name: "Image4",
    image_id: "3",
    source: "images/img4.png",
  },
  {
    image_name: "Image5",
    image_id: "4",
    source: "images/img5.png",
  },
  {
    image_name: "Image6",
    image_id: "5",
    source: "images/img6.png",
  },
  {
    image_name: "Image7",
    image_id: "6",
    source: "images/img7.png",
  },
  {
    image_name: "Image8",
    image_id: "7",
    source: "images/img8.png",
  }
]
      
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // data.length returns 8
  // creation of the images
  let images = document.createElement('img')
  images.setAttribute('class', 'image')
  document.querySelector('.container-image-to-place').append(images)// It displays automatically the 8 images
}

images = document.querySelectorAll('.image')
// assign each values to the good image
data.forEach(({source, image_name, image_id}, i) => {
  images[i].src = source
  images[i].alt = image_name
  images[i].id = image_id
})
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container-image-to-place">
<!-- the images are displayed here -->
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are wanting to do. Why are you only wanting to loop 4 items? What criteria is that based on? Either way one solution would be to put a condition in your `data.forEach`

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) does not produce a new array...  Of course, it would be simple enough to do `if (i < 4) images.classList.add('show');` and add CSS like `.image { display: none; } .image.show {display: inline;}`

Comment: @ElRonnoco. I want to change all my object into <img> (in the html way) and THEN show the first 4 but if I delete one of these 4 I want the next <img> to come automatically to take its place. 
I'id like to have something like a line of images and when I drag and drop one into another div (I delete this img/obj from the data-array. I know how to do this with drag and drop event!) another images comes on the screen with the 3 left. 
In my code if I put a i < 4. The other images won't be created. do you see what I mean ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. But if you want to process the first 4 items without modifying the array you can do...

```
  data.forEach(({source, image_name, image_id}, i) => {
    if (i < 4) {
        images[i].src = source
        images[i].alt = image_name
        images[i].id = image_id
    }
  });
```

This however isn't particularly elegant though as if you had an array of 1000 object it would need to perform the condition for each one. As you suggest it would be better to use `.slice`...

```
  // untested!
  data.slice(0, 4).forEach(({source, image_name, image_id}, i) => {
    images[i].src = source
    images[i].alt = image_name
    images[i].id = image_id
  });
```

This won't alter your `data` array but will create a new copy of the first 4 items.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop is useful if you want to loop through all your images, however if you only want to loop through 4 of them why not use a while loop like this:

```
while (i < 4) {
  // code block to be executed
  i++;
}
```